# I created a comment section in my Django project and i want to redirect users to that same post they just commented on after they posted the comment

Tags: python, django, redirect, comments, review

right now it redirects them to the home page. here is the views.py file:

```
class AddReviewView(CreateView):
model = Review
form_class = ReviewForm
template_name = 'blog/add_review.html'
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['pk']
    return super().form_valid(form)
success_url = reverse_lazy('blog-home')
```

and here is the models.py file:

```
class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
price = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
post_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='post_images/')
content = models.TextField()
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})



class Review(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="reviews", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.post.title, self.name)
```

here are my url patterns:

```
 urlpatterns = [

    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
    path('marketplace/', MarketplaceView.as_view(), name='blog-marketplace'),
    path('freelancers/', FreelancersView.as_view(), name='blog-freelancers'),
    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='blog-about'),
    path('search-posts/', views.search_posts, name='search_posts'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/Review/', AddReviewView.as_view(), name='add_review'),
 ]
```

pleae help me!!
note: i want to change the success_url = reverse_lazy('blog-home') to redirect the the page they just commented on

Answer (score 0):

*Can't comment, that's why answering here*

You might want to change the success url to the post and pass the ID of the post

Comment: what do you mean? `success_url = reverse_lazy('blog-home')` should be changed to something like: `success url = Post.id`??